# Is the new Gmail just a modernization of the interface?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I use G Suite for 12 years now and started with the Gmail interface which did not change that much until now.

I then moved to Inbox as it was bringing in brand new functionalities (especially the automatic classification for interesting areas such as travel).

Then the new Gmail came in recently (I noticed it today on my G Suite console) and gave it a try.

As far as I can tell, this is **exactly** the old Gmail with a better looking interface. Functionality wise nothing has changed (except for the addition of shortcuts on the right). In particular, the `Parameters` section is exactly the old one (it almost looks like an iframe with the old content).

**Has any new major functionality been added?**

I was hoping for some kind of mashup between the old Gmail and Inbox, but did not find anything new so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick search reveals that it's more than simply a shiny new interface. (Start with the [Google Blog](https://www.blog.google/products/g-suite/new-security-and-intelligent-features-new-gmail-means-business/), for instance.)

Some of the new features include:

- Confidential Mode: Send email with expiration dates or revoking previously sent messages. Also allows the option to prevent copying, forwarding, downloading, or printing.
- Smart reply - Offers options for quickly replying based on the context of the message and your previous responses.
- Nudges - reminds you of messages you may have forgotten about, or replies you're still waiting on.
- Tighter integration with Calendar, Keep, and Tasks. Also, Tasks has been resurrected and refreshed.
- Native offline capabilities (no longer requires a browser extension)
- Action icons in the conversation list - hover your mouse over a row and buttons to archive, delete, mark as read, or snooze. Calendar invitations add buttons for RSVP and decline.
- Snooze - this is directly ported from Inbox.
- Plus mentions - add someone to your CC list without leaving the body of your message. Hit `+` and choose the name from your contacts.
- Attachments now offer a button in the conversation list too, so you can open an attachment without opening the message.
- For mobile, there's high-priority notifications. Certain messages that the AI has learned are important will send you a push notification on your Android or iOS device.